# React select not rendering selected values in it's search box

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-select-search

In my homepage, I have react-select component. It's works as expected.

But after selecting any value, If go to another route and come back, React-Select not showing that value in search box. Although, the selected value is removed from the drop-down menu. But not showing only in Search Box.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far to solve this by providing code snippets. It will be easier to help you.